# Using ShowCaseView for fragments

Tags: android-fragments, showcaseview

When I tried to search for this, I got many solutions which mention use of function insertShowcaseView with some parameters which works well for fragments.
But I am unable to find this function in my downloaded library of showcaseview.
Can anyone provide me with latest source of library which includes features for implementing it for fragments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ShowCaseView v5 builder with fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805816/how-to-use-showcaseview-v5-builder-with-fragments)

Answer (score 1):

You may find this question and answer useful: [How to use ShowCaseView v5 builder with fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805816/how-to-use-showcaseview-v5-builder-with-fragments)

For your information, the v5 API has changed significantly, hence why the insertShowcaseView methods are no longer available. Please see the [GitHub project](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) for examples and sample code!

Comment: v5 is no more compatible with android sdk version 10 ? Is that correct or there is a workaround for the gradle error, stating its minimum required sdk is 11 ?