# How to use ShowCaseView v5 builder with fragments?

Tags: android, showcaseview

I found examples for the legacy version, but not for the new builder pattern. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Builder constructor only needs an activity `public Builder(Activity activity)` so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    showcaseView = new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTarget(new ViewTarget(view.findViewById(R.id.textView)))
            .setOnClickListener(listener)
            .build();
    ....
```

Comment: This would work for an activity, but not for a fragment... I can only `getActivity()` in `onActivityCreated()`, but there I can't `findViewById()` (the views aren't measured yet so I'll get an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`).

Comment: @MichaelLitvin that's why you have to do it in the `onCreateView` method. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll update the sample and example code to show how to do this for other users!